# ps command: list processes by group id

Tags: linux, ps

Here is what I get when I list all processes with -g option:

```
ps -g -o pid,pgid,ppid
   PID   PGID   PPID
112140 112140 112139
127467 127467 127466
130547 130547 112140
130551 130547 130547
130557 130557 127467
```

...

```
ps -g 130547
```

displays nothing, while I would expect 130547 and 130551. Same for 'ps -s '.
Why? Is there a way to display processes belonging to the same group (tree)?

Comment: Maybe `pstree -g 130547`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, `ps -g` selects processes either by *group* or by *session*, but not by *process group*. It treats the arguments as session IDs if they consist solely of digits and as group names otherwise.

`ps -g 130547` lists all the processes in the session whose ID is 130547. Presumably process 130547 is not a session leader and therefore there is no process whose session ID is 130547.

Linux ps doesn't have an option to filter by process group. You can list all the processes, or all the processes in a given session, and filter by the `pgid` field.

```
ps -g $(ps -p 130547 -o sid=) -o pid,ppid,pgid
ps -e -o pid,ppid,pgid | awk 'NR == 1 || $3 == 130547'
```